# Robocopy /MOVE, directory\tree not recreated, Win-11\Home

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, robocopy

The line below previously worked with Win-10\Home; dir\tree remained intact.

```
robocopy D:\ A:\Bak_Up /E /ZB /dcopy:dat /LOG:A:\Bak_Up.log /TEE
```

---

By comparison, using Win-11\Home from the below .bat, will not create the dir tree; Robocopy dumps the individual files in the dest dir.

```bash
@echo off

Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

cd /d A:\45011

robocopy %CD% E:\45011\TEMP_08_Day_From_A /S /ZB /MOVE /LOG:E:\45011\TEMP_08_Day_From_A\_08_Days.log /TEE
```

---

`Robocopy /?` -- clearly states, `/MOVE :: MOVE files AND dirs (delete from source after copying).`

It does not specify to use `/MOVE` with any other option to recreate the original dir tree. However, the following within a .bat, does recreate and/or `move` the dir tree. The notable difference is the destination.

```bash
@echo off

Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

cd /d A:\45011

robocopy %CD% E:\45011 /S /E /ZB /MOVE /LOG:E:\45011\TEMP_08_Day_From_A\_08_Days.log /TEE
```

---

- Question 1) What is the above issue causing the confusion between what the help file states should be the resulting output, compared to the actual `Robocopy` output?

---

Below is more evidence that `Robocopy`, or `cmd.exe`, is just plain misbehaving.

From an elevated prompt:

```bash
A:\45011>For /f %i in ('dir /b ') do robocopy %i E:\45011\TEMP_08_Day_From_A /XD 2024*2? /S /ZB /MOVE /LOG:E:\45011\TEMP_08_Day_From_A\_08_Days.log /TEE
```

Initally, using the above command-line, the dir tree was in-fact being recreated in the dest\path, then deleted from the src\path. There was a brief regional power-outage for approximately five minutes; then Rcopy resumed, unknown at the resumed time, the bare files were now being dumped into the dest\path; no more dir\tree.

Subsequently there was another brief pwr-loss, this is when we discovered the dir\tree was no longer being recreated. We then manually cancelled with ^C; then restarted using the same elevated prompt and line shown above. The bare files continue to be dumped in the dest\path without any sub-directories.

Even though there was a pwr-loss, the machine remained 'on' battery. The usb-connected drives needed to wait for power restoration.

---

- Question 2) What might be causing the above behavior?

Last item of Rcopy misbehaving, see image showing `dir /b` in the 'left' elevated prompt, compared to the active Rcopy output, seen in the 'right'. Rcopy appears to be writing files that no longer exist in that dir; or anywhere on that hdd.

To be clear, the parent dir is `A:\45011` containing a list of sub-dir's named yyyymmdd.

- Question 3) What might be causing this problem shown in the image?

### [image: Robocopy output (right), is writing files that no longer exist.]

Below is what currently works:

```bash
@echo off

Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

cd /d A:\45011
robocopy %CD% C:\45011 /S /E /ZB /DCOPY:DAT /MT:16 /MOVE /XD 2024*3? "Download Record" "Manual Capture" "Manual Record" VMS_ALARM_Sounds _Reports /LOG:C:\45011\_Days.log /TEE
```

---

Our Goal is to `/COPY` or `/MOVE` the original `dir\tree` to any custom-named dir, not an exact match of the original parent-dir name.